# I try to save many lines in a txt file using isolated storage in WP7 but it will only saves one, how do I save many?

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-7, streamwriter, isolatedstorage

I use this to save the score everytime the game is over

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
isf.CreateDirectory("Data");
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data\\scoretest.txt", FileMode.Create, isf));
sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") + "                                   Score: " + punc);
sw.Close();
```

and to read from the txt I use a for that stops when the reading is null

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
StreamReader sr = null;
try
{
    sr = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(@"Data\scoretest.txt", FileMode.Open, isf));
    for (;;)
    {
        string x = sr.ReadLine();
        if (x == null)
           break;
        else
            listBox1.Items.Add(x);
    }
    sr.Close();
}
catch
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("");
}
```

It only charges the last line, Why it doesn't read more than one line?

Answer (score 2):

FileMode.Create will overwrite the file every time. You should use FileMode.OpenOrCreate or FileMode.Append instead(ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx)

Also, take a look at the Isolated Storage Explorer tool to verify your file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408(v=VS.92).aspx